# How does "EnableLevel" in Autologger\EventLog work?

Tags: windows, event-log

I want to filter out Warnings, but keep Errors and Critical events in Event Viewer for a particular event.

Does `"EnableLevel"=dword:00000002` accomplish this?

For example

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\WMI\Autologger\EventLog-System\{1c95126e-7eea-49a9-a3fe-a378b03ddb4d}]
"EnableLevel"=dword:00000002
; Default = 0, everything is logged
```

The Warning events I'm trying to filter from my System Log happen randomly and sometimes days between events, so it's very difficult to determine if changing the value actually works.

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/configuring-and-starting-an-autologger-session) seem to indicate that `2` is what I want to only log Error and Critical-level events.

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntrace/nf-evntrace-enabletraceex)

> Microsoft defines the semantics of levels 1-5 as shown below.

```
| Value                       | Meaning                                    |
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| TRACE_LEVEL_CRITICAL (1)    | Abnormal exit or termination events        |
| TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR (2)       | Severe error events                        |
| TRACE_LEVEL_WARNING (3)     | Warning events such as allocation failures |
| TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION (4) | Non-error informational events             |
| TRACE_LEVEL_VERBOSE (5)     | Detailed diagnostic events                 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get creative to test this, but I'm confident I've learned the following:

```
- EnableLevel 0 = Logs all events
- EnableLevel 1 = Logs Critical
- EnableLevel 2 = Logs Critical, Error
- EnableLevel 3 = Logs Critical, Error, Warning
- EnableLevel 4 = Logs Critical, Error, Warning, Information
- EnableLevel 5 = Logs Critical, Error, Warning, Information, Verbose
```

Notes: There are other levels besides 0-5. I'm not sure what *Verbose* logs, probably for debugging. I've seen levels as high as 255, probably also for debugging.

From what I can tell, a bitmask value does not work. In other words, there is no `OR` operator to choose to log, for example, `Critical OR Information` only.

I can find no documentation for an answer anywhere, so hopefully this helps someone. If anyone has first-hand knowledge of the proper canonical answer, post it and I'll mark it correct.